# How to translate MIPS into C and how to reduce MIPS instructions？

Tags: mips

Supposing that f, g, h, i are stored in $s0~$s4  respectively and the base addresses of arrays A and B are in  $S6 and $S7.

```
sll  $t0, $s0, 2
add $t0, $s6, $t0
sll $tl, $sl, 2
add $tl, $s7, $tl
lw $s0, 0($t0)
addi $t2 , $t0, 4
lw $t0, 0($t2)
add $t0, $t0, $s0
SW $t0, 0($tl)
```

I'm not familiar with MIPS so I Wonder how to translate MIPS into C and how to minimize these MIPS instructions？

Comment: Here is a instruction reference. Use the meaning column for getting equivalent C code. https://www.dsi.unive.it/~gasparetto/materials/MIPS_Instruction_Set.pdf BTW $s0 to $s4 are 5 registers vs. 4 C variable names f, g, h, i. $tn are temporary registers, $sn are saved registers. They are translated to the actual register numbers by the assembler.

Comment: I'm assuming all your variables are `int`s or arrays of `int`s, but in order to do this you'll need to know.

Answer (score 1):

> how to translate MIPS into C

You recognize the patterns, here for array indexing / array element access.

On a byte addressable machine (all modern hardware), a 4-byte integer occupies 4 bytes in memory, and each of those bytes has a unique memory address.  Because of the way the hardware works, we only use one of those 4 addresses to refer to the whole 4-byte integer, namely we use the lowest address among the 4.  The hardware can load a 4-byte integer from memory given that one address (the lowest).

Since each 4-byte integer in memory occupies 4 addresses, in an array of 4-byte integers, the memory address of the first element and the memory address of the second element are 4 addresses apart even though are sequential index positions (i.e. they are only 1 index position apart).

The formula for indexing a 4-byte integer array, then is to convert the index into a byte offset, then add the byte offset to the base address of the array.  The first part of that: converting an index to a byte offset, is sometimes referred to as "scaling".  Scaling is conceptually done by multiplication, so in `A[i]`, `i` needs to be scaled by the size of the array elements of `A`.  If 4-byte integers that means scaling (multiplying) the index  by 4.  A quick way of doing that is shifting by 2 bit positions, which has the same effect as multiplying by 4.

The C language automatically scales when doing array references, whereas assembly language requires explicit scaling.  C can do this because it knows the type of the array, whereas assembly language does not.

In C we can do expressions like `A[i]`.  The C language allows us to break that down somewhat into `*(A+i)`, which separates the pointer arithmetic addition `A+i` from the dereferencing of that sum, dereferencing with the unary indirection operator, `*`.  As previously mentioned, C automatically scales, so `A+i` becomes the equivalent of `A+i*4`, in which we can substitute shifting for multiplication: `A+(i<<2)`.

Next, we need to know if the dereference is for read or for write.  When `A[i]` is accessed for its value, we will see it on what we call the "right hand side" of an assignment operator, as in `... = A[i]`.  When `A[i]` is access to update/store a value, we will see it on what we call the `left hand side` of an assignment operator, as in `A[i] = ...`.

So, the sequence for doing `A[i]` for read (right hand side) in C is the following in assembly:

```
sll $temp1, $i, 2
addu $temp2, $A, $temp1
lw $temp3, 0($temp1)
```

Where $tempN is some register (usually a designated temporary) chosen to hold an intermediate value.  Since multiple instructions are needed to accomplish anything, sequences of instructions are interconnected with registers that hold the intermediate states.  And also, in assembly we name registers, not variables, so in my above `$i` and `$A` should be a registers names representing those variables rather than variable names directly used.

The pattern for write/store array access is similar but ends with a `sw` instruction instead, to store some value into memory at the index position.

These instruction sequence are interconnected by the use of these registers, and the sequences can be interrupted or interspersed with other instructions — what we have to follow then is the above pattern by paying attention to to the register usages that interconnect them rather than the specific sequences.

In your sample code:

```
sll  $t0, $s0, 2     # sourcing an index in $s0, scaling it into temp $t0
add $t0, $s6, $t0    # adding a base array in $s6, putting back into $t0
sll $tl, $sl, 2      
add $tl, $s7, $tl
lw $s0, 0($t0)       # accessing the value of $s6[$s0*4], aka A[f]
addi $t2 , $t0, 4
lw $t0, 0($t2)
add $t0, $t0, $s0
SW $t0, 0($tl)
```

We can see the pattern for a read access to an index in `$s0`, and an array in `$s6`, these, we are told, map to `f` and `A`, so those three instructions comprise `A[f]` to read a value from `A` at index `f`.

The rest are done similarly.  Your job is to use this knowledge to find the other array indexing patterns in the above sequence.  Find out how the results of the array indexing operations are used and you'll have the complete C code.

---

NOTE that the sample you've been given incorrectly  uses `add` and `addi` when pointer arithmetic should use `addu` and `addiu` — we don't want signed integer overflow checking on pointer arithmetic, as pointers are unsigned.

One of the `add` instructions is not for pointer arithmetic, but should probably still have used `addu` if this is intended to be replicated in C, because the C language does not have a built in operator to trap on overflow.

Comment: Nice explanation!